# Align vertical cell tabular

Tags: tables, align

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xr}
\textbf{Sample Text\hfill\break next line} & aligin bottom right \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

how to make second column align bottom right, now it is align top right

something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could issue the instruction `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}}` after loading the `tabularx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}X r}
\textbf{Sample Text\hfill\break next line} 
& align bottom right \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: simple and nice, thx but if i want make third column with align top right

Comment: @chose - I'm a notoriously poor psychic: I've never been any good at answering questions that aren't actually asked... :-) It would help if you edited your posting to show which table structure you're actually interested in.